# WSL Interoperability: Open Windows 10 applications w/ Bash (Windows Linux Subsystem)

Tags: 16.04, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the latest Windows Subsystem for Linux [Build 14986](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14986) `(Ubuntu 16.04 - Xenial)`, and I want the ability to open up Window 10 applications directly from bash prompt by typing a command.

Also, it would be great if I could open up Linux files the same way *(vice versa)* w/ Visual Studio Code *(Windows Application)*. Is this possible now w/ [WSL Interoperability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/10/19/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability/)? This new feature was released in [Build 14951](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14951), but I'm unsure of it's full capability.

---

#### Example

Typing `code .` inside the bash prompt would open up the `www` folder in my default editor (Visual Studio Code).

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here? The blog post says you can, but you tried and you couldn't?

Comment: Hi @muru, I'm a 1 week old newb with bash coming from a Windows world, so please forgive my ignorance. I did attempt this (before I upgraded to Interop)..To make a long story short, this is my 6th or 7th install. I asked the question here to get pro advice. I'm not sure if a command already exists, or if I should create a custom script, or make an alias, or something better. I've watched the video that I linked, but haven't read completely through the blog yet (that's next).

Comment: That .. still doesn't make things clear - advice for what? Command/script/alias for what?

Comment: I'm asking: how to create a command to open my default code editor?

This 2-minute video explains exactly what I'm wanting to do..but this is for OSX: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF7X6KJ6vBA

Comment: can you run notepad from WSL?

Comment: you can run any Windows App from WSL. See `notepad.exe` opening up here: https://youtu.be/EdAXrHctFu0 ,,, The reason I asked the question here was to get the standard, simplified approach.

Comment: you missed the point of my question . You have something in mind, it's just now clear what it is - Are you having problems running Windows apps from WSL? Or you can run them, but you want shortcuts? You say "standard simplified approach", so what is your current approach?

Comment: My question is multi-part... But it starts off with: How can I open up a Windows App ("VScode" for this example) by typing a single command in the bash terminal,`code .` (like youtube example)? The next question: By using my new command `code .` to open up VScode, is it possible to edit and save files that are located in Linux folders `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\lxss\root` ?

Comment: and what happens if you run `VScode` now?

Comment: `justin@Oneezy:/mnt/c/Users/Justin$ code`
No command 'code' found, did you mean:

Comment: `justin@Oneezy:/mnt/c/Users/Justin$ VScode`
VScode: command not found

Comment: An alias doesn't exist for VScode. Bash has no idea what it is. But, if I were using the Windows Git Bash (git-scm.com), writing the command `code .` would work out of the box (not sure why). However, My goal is to move completely away from Windows terminals and strictly use Bash for web development. Windows terminals like git-scm, minTTy and cygwin only get you so far and have weird problems that come with it. Linux is the real deal though, and that's why I'm taking the time out to re-create my workflow in the linux world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51353/discussion-between-muru-and-oneezy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Atom as my code editor. Typing `atom somefile.py` opens the Python file in Atom regardless of whether or not I type it in Windows or Linux on the subsystem.

It sounds like you want this same functionality, but instead of typing `atom`, you want to have your own custom command.

This can be done with aliases. For example, if I type `alias code='atom $1'` into the Linux bash, and then type `code somefile.py`, it opens in Atom.

These aliases will disappear once you close the bash window, so most people instead put them in a file called `~/.bashrc` which is automatically run when you open a new Linux bash window, so your command will be ready to use all the time.